# Add class to element based on date

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, events

I have a span element that looks like this.
html

```
<span class="tribe-event-date-start">September 5 @ 7:00 pm</span>
```

I would like to target that element by its date and add a class to its parent container.

The class is intended to highlight the container if the current date matches the date in the element.  Note, I can only get the Month and Day here, so that's all that needs to match.  I am not a JS or JQuery expert at all, but get the basics, I know I can utilize one of the two to produce the end result.

This is the output of the WordPress plugin "The Events Calendar" widget to display upcoming events.

The end result should be a class added to the parent div IF the element date matches the actual day's date.

Comment: at the moment, how are you getting the month and day, and what function are you trying to use to compare month and day to some date? Those are important information that should be on your question

Answer (score 0):

If you can trust the output will always look like that you can do something like:

```
var _dateToCheck = $(".tribe-event-date-start").text();
_dateToCheck = _dateToCheck.substring(0,_dateToCheck.indexOf("@"));
_dateToCheck.trim();

var _current = new Date();
console.log(_dateToCheck.getMonth(), _dateToCheck.getDate(), _current .getMonth(), _current.getDate());
```

so then you can do your comparison checks against the month, then followed by the date.

If that class "tribe-event-date-start" is actually what needs to be applied to the element, then you would do that after your date comparison logic... but you still need something to seach on, so if you don't have a class or an ID to start with then you're going to have to use the actual element, but I'd still try and whittle that list down a bit - something like:

```
var _allTheRows = $("#my-calendar-plugin-thing span");
_allTheRows.each(checkDate); 

function checkDate(el){
    var _dateToCheck = $(el).text();
    _dateToCheck = _dateToCheck.substring(0,_dateToCheck.indexOf("@"));
    _dateToCheck.trim();

    var _current = new Date();
    console.log(_dateToCheck.getMonth(), _dateToCheck.getDate(), _current 
    .getMonth(), _current.getDate());

   //... check if date is greater or smaller or the same, or whatever your logic is

    if(meetsMyCondition){$(el).parent().addClass("tribe-event-date-star")}

}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'll give this a shot and post back.  Much appreciated!